# Using python's geocoder without Google API KEY

Tags: python, google-geocoder

I'm using python [geocoder library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder) this way:

```
import geocoder

g = geocoder.google(search_address)
```

However, I'm not indicating anywhere in the code my Google API key. For a while (about 6 months) it was working correctly, however these last days it seems that it fails to geocode for some specific addresses.

So my question is why this was working in the first place anyway (without any Google API Key) ?  and why it is not now.

Comment: Keyless access to web services wasn't deprecated yet, although Google strongly recommends using an API key in order to have your own per project quota and do not use a shared quota for keyless access. Can you see any error message? Can you post some examples of addresses that cannot be geocoded?

Comment: @xomena , that was probably related to the key. The error message was QUERY_LIMIT. It is solved now that I'm using my own key. Thanks